# Assign value numbers for alphabet in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have alphabets that I want to assign as follows:

lowercase items a-z have value of 1-26
uppercase items A-Z have value of 27-52

What is the shortest way to implement this

[a,B,h,R]
Expected Output:
[1,28,8,44]

How can we go about doing this in Python

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The python [string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) module is perfect for this.

```
from string import ascii_letters
print([ascii_letters.index(letter) + 1 for letter in ["a", "B", "h", "R"]])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I recognize an Advent of Code question! I developed the alphabet to score mapping as follows:

```
import string
from collections import OrderedDict
lower_priorities = OrderedDict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, range(1,27)))
upper_priorities = OrderedDict(zip(string.ascii_uppercase, range(27,53)))
```

You can then call the dictionary by the letter value you are interested in after checking whether is is uppercase or lowercase and then sorting it to the correct dictionary. Otherwise, combine the two dictionaries and just query the combined dictionary, i.e. `lower_priorities["a"]` would return `1`. Loop through your array and obtain your outputs. Can't guarantee it's the shortest, but I can say it works!

Answer (score 0):

This is a way that you can implement what you want:

```
print([ord(item) - 38 if ord(item) < 97 else ord(item) - 96 for item in ['a','B','h','R']])
```

converting each item into an int value and finding which positioning they are in (Capitalized letters come before lowercase)

https://appdividend.com/2022/06/15/how-to-convert-python-char-to-int/